# Own implementation of array_unique()

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$number = array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c");
```

Now I want to get all unique values. Means the result should be:

```
$result = array("a", "b", "c");
```

Now I know that this can easily be solved with `array_unique()`. But I want to write my own little implementation of `array_unique()` just using a for loop, `unset()` and `array_values()`.

Comment: Just use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). I don't know how you could have spent three hours on this when a quick google search would have solved this in minutes.

Comment: Why not use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Do You Have To Use Those Functions Or You Can Do Using Another Function?

Comment: It Can Be Easily Solved By That. I Know. But I want To Use for(), unset() and array_values(). If U have The Logic For That.Let Me Know.

Comment: Why you trying  to make your code much complicated!!

Comment: Well. Im still Developing My Logic Skill. So Its A Challenge To Me. And Maybe For You Too. Im Not Searching For The "Soft Way".

Comment: Well My Full Method I can List It Here. for(),array_values,unset(),count(),if(). My real code Made me Has To Use implode(),explode(),str_replace(),trim()

Comment: Was this a homework ?

Answer (score 0):

use  array_unique()

```
<?php
    $number=array("a","b","b","c","a","b","c","b","c");
    $unique_array=array_unique($number);
    print_r($unique_array);
?>
```

//second posibility

```
<?php
    $number=array("a","b","b","c","a","b","c","b","c");
    $unique_array=[];
    foreach($number as $val)
    {
        $unique_array[$val]=$val;
    }
    print_r(array_values($unique_array));
?>
```

//Third posibility with for,unset,array_value

```
<?php
$number=array("a","b","b","c","a","b","c","b","c");
$count=count($number);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if($i<count($number))
    {
        for($j=$i+1;$j<$count;$j++)
        {
            if($number[$i]==$number[$j])
            {
                unset($number[$j]);
             }
        }

    }
}
$number=array_values($number);
print_r($number);
```

?>

expected result is

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
```

Comment: Did U have To Use array_unique For That? Could You Tell Me How To Eliminate Those Duplicates Using for(), unset(), and array_values() ?

Comment: sure give me few mins, i will

Comment: In This Code it Is A Must To Compare the Same Array Like `$number[0]==$number[0]`. Could U Avoid That?

Comment: check now , i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? Here we are looping through and array starting in one `for` from the position 0 and in the other from 1. We compare the `$i` position with all the others in array and if it finds two same it removes the second one.

```
<?php
    $number = array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c");
    $count = count($number);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            if(isset($number[$j]) && isset($number[$i]) && $number[$i] == $number[$j]) {
                unset($number[$j]);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($number);
```

Comment: Just Like That. Now Im Trying To Understand It. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a small description of the solution

Comment: How Many Minutes U Need To Solve This Btw?

Comment: Few minutes because i was thinking why would you need `array_values`. I have this logic because i was working with C which doesn't have cool functions like `array_unique`, `array_search` etc